# How CSS with Master Page and new content page with own css that should not override masterpage header and footer?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages, activereports

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 website that uses a master page.  I link a CSS page that is used throughout the site.  I added a new page that uses the master page and the page has it's own css for content area cause it is used with an Active Reports viewer.

When I go to the new page with the Active Reports Viewer, it's CSS is overriding the CSS from the master page for header and footer which I do not want to do.

Any recommendations on only allowing the new CSS file only affecting the contentarea of my new page.

Comment: This seems to be purely an issue of CSS specificity rather than anything to do with asp.net.  General rules on which rules override which rules are based on the specificity of the CSS rule.  Specificities being equal, the last rule on the page will win.  If you do not want to apply the header and footer styles in your Active Reports Viewer page, is there a page in which you do want those rules?  Making the undesired CSS header/footer rules more specific (and tying them to the context in which you do want them to apply) might resolve your issue.

Comment: May be you need scoped css. This css trick might help you. https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: @VivekN `scoped` did not make it past the definition stage. It may survive for a while (not forever) in Firefox, but it will never be implemented in other browsers.

Comment: @JPJedi I don't understand the question, by the way. I read it a couple of times, but all I read is "I made a new stylesheet. It overrides the original stylesheet and I don't want that." Then why not simply get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't limit the scope of a css to only the content; it applies to the entire page. What you can do is to give a different name to the class in the stylesheet for the content page and assign it to the header and footer sections. For eg.

```
.contentpage-custom {
    background-color: red;
}

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
   <header class="contentpage-custom">
     Content Page
   </header>
</asp:Content>
```